# Is it possible to add a cookie on a different domain request with nginx?

Tags: nginx, cookies, nginx-reverse-proxy

So this is my context:

I have a frontend local app on port 4203.
A nginx server on port 3000 would point all requests at **'/'** to **localhost:4203**
all requests to **localhost:3000/api** are proxied to **https://example.com/api** which would also set a cookie on my browser. After acquiring the cookie, every request to a relative path like **/api/resource** work fine with the cookie included in the header.
The problem is that I have some absolute links on my frontend app which I would like not having to parse them. So I'll have requests to **https://example.com/api/anotherResource** on which I can't apply the cookie for some reason so they are failing.

Is it even possible to add the cookies on this absolute path requests ?

Or maybe a way to proxy requests at https:/example.com/api/anotherResource to first acquire the cookie on localhost.

here is my nginx config:

```
server {
  listen       3000;
  server_name  localhost;

  location ^ ~ /api/ {
    proxy_pass    https://example.com/api;
    }
  location / {
    proxy_pass    http://localhost:4203;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `proxy_set_header Cookie "name=value";`. You can either add that to location specific block or for testing to all blocks

Comment: that won't work because the request is not on localhost so none of the location blocks I added in the example would be hit when accesing https://example.com/api.....

Comment: So there are two parts to cookies, one is sending cookies and once is receiving cookies. Which means `example.com` cookies are set inside `localhost` cookies when response comes back. What solution I give will always send the cookies to your `example.com` server as such. But the receiving cookies won't be sent back. So what do you want?